# Ajax - post data to many pages

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm new in ajax, and i want to send my data to multiple pages, i have "fetch.php" and "index.php", i tried to do something like this, and it does absolutely nothing.

```
function load_product(minimum_range, maximum_range, selection)
{
    $.ajax({
        url:{"index.php","fetch.php"},
        method:"POST",
        data:{minimum_range:minimum_range, maximum_range:maximum_range,"selection": sv},
        success:function(data)
        {
            $('#load_product').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

How can i do that ?

Comment: Is your project a single page application? Otherwise you can only load the data on the page you're at.

Comment: @Emily i have 2 php pages "fetch.php" and "index.php" i need to send to both of them those 3 variables, and yes i want the data to be loud only on "index.php"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not send rame request to multiple links by passing multiple urls in url. What you can do is run a loop of urls and then doing ajax calls on all the urls

```js
function load_product(minimum_range, maximum_range, selection)
{
    var links = ["index.php","fetch.php"]; 
    links.forEach(function(link){
      $.ajax({
          url:link,
          method:"POST",
          data:{minimum_range:minimum_range, maximum_range:maximum_range,"selection": sv},
          success:function(data)
          {
              $('#load_product').html(data);
          }
      });
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's not working, i also set the missing ";" but it's not sending to any page.

Comment: Actually it is working, there was a missing "s" (links.foreach) but it's a little bit shaky, i'll see what i can do, thanks anyway.